# Special non-negative matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, stochastic-matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Assume we have the following decomposition: $M=AWA^T$

Where:

$M$ is non-negative symmetric (i.e. $M_{i,j}\ge{0}$ and $M_{i,j}=M_{j,i}$)

$A$ is right stochastic (entries are non-negative and rows sum to 1)

$W$ is non-negative and symmetric

My questions are whether this kind of decomposition has been studied and specifically whether it is unique (excluding permutation and multiplication by a constant).

Comment: No, it cannot be unique, here is a way to construct arbitrarily many counterexamples: Take any nonnegative symmetric $W$ and any two right stochastic $A_1,A_2$. Let $M=A_1A_2WA_2^TA_1^T$. Then $M$ has at least two such decompositions: $M=(A_1A_2)W(A_1A_2)^T$ and $M=A_1(A_2WA_2^T)A_1^T$.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, would you like to paste this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric matrix $W = W^T$ can be written as follow
$$ W = Q \Lambda Q^T,   \qquad\text{(spectral theorem)}$$

where $\Lambda $ is a diagonal matrix and symmetric ($\Lambda = \Lambda^T$), and $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Thus, we can write

$$\begin{align*}
M &= AQ\Lambda Q^TA^T \\
  &= (AQ)\Lambda (AQ)^T\\
  &= C\Lambda C^T
\end{align*}$$

where $C=AQ$

If $W$ is real positive-definite, then

$$ W = LL^T \qquad \qquad \text{(using Cholesky decomposition)}$$

Substituting this into the expression of $M$ we get

$$\begin{align*}
M &= AWA^T \\
  &= ALL^TA^T\\
  &= AL(AL)^T
\end{align*}$$

So, the decomposition is not unique.